# Chrome Extension Manifest V3 with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Does anyone know of or have any information on integrating a Manifest V3 Chrome extension with a Firebase real-time database? If not, does anyone have any information on integrating any real-time database with a Manifest V3 Chrome extension? I've been at this for about a week and have only found Manifest V2 integration, User authentication, or broken code.